# Unable to build my app in API23 with volley library on windows

Tags: java, android, windows, android-volley

Build log:

:volley:javadoc

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'javadoc' during up-to-date check.  See stacktrace for details.

Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\JC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;C:\Users\JC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar'.

This issue is occurring only on windows. With the same setup build goes fine on mac.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Android SDK to api v23

Comment: It is on v23 already. Started getting this problem after I added volley.

Answer (score 0):

1. Removed volley project, its dependencies in settings.gradle and build.gradle
2. Removed apache http legacy jar dependency
3. Added http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.0 this jar in my build dependencies.

This built my project fine. However, its not the official volley jar.

Comment: this is an option but this library is already deprecated. you can use https://github.com/apptik/jus
it is based on volley but there are alot of improvements and new features but you can reuse your volley code with little changes